# unpickling in w+b mode in python

Tags: python, exception, pickle, eoferror

i tried to do unpickling using w+b mode.
i got the exception EOFError: ran out of input.
why is unpickling not possible in w+b mode? w+b mode also offers reading a binary file right then why am i getting this exception and what does ran out of input means in here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening a file in `w+b` [will truncate the file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open). If you want to open a file for reading and writing without truncation, you should use `r+b`.